# Why do I get permission error when trying to read from a collectionGroup?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, firebase-security

I am building an app where users can make posts. I had something working with no issues, but then I started putting things in subcollections and now get some permission errors. Wondering if someone can help check this out and let me know if you spot anything I am doing wrong here.

I am trying to simply read the data here.

I commented out the code that works (see below). Now, I want to put the `posts` collection in a subcollection under the `users` collection and this is causing a permissions issue.

This is the console error I get:

`client.js?06a0:51 error fetching posts Error [FirebaseError]: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Here's the model:
[image: data model]

and here is the code where I am fetching the data:

```
  async fetch() {
    try {
      // const postsArr = []
      // const postsCol = await this.$fire.firestore
      //   .collection('posts')
      //   .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      //   .limit(5)
      //   .get()
      // postsCol.forEach((doc) => postsArr.push(doc.data()))
      // this.posts = postsArr
      const postsArr = []
      const postsQuery = await this.$fire.firestore
        .collectionGroup('posts')
        .where('published', '==', true)
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .limit(1)
        .get()
      postsQuery.forEach((doc) => postsArr.push(doc.data()))
      this.posts = postsArr
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error fetching posts', error)
    }
  },
```

Finally, here are my security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
  // lock down all paths and open up as needed. IS THIS REALLY NEEDED? THOUGHT IT WAS COMPUTER SEC 101?
  allow read, write: if false;
  }
  
  // Required for collection group queries
  match /posts/{postId} {
    allow read;
  }
  
  match /usernames/{username} {
    allow read;
    allow create: if isValidUsername(username);
  }
  
  match /users/{uid} {
    allow read;
    allow write: if isUser(uid) && isSignedIn() && emailVerified();
  }
  

  match /users/{uid}/posts/{postId} {
    allow read;
    allow create;
    // allow create: if canCreatePost(uid); 
    // allow update: if canUpdatePost(userId) || canIncrementHearts(userId, postId);
    // allow delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  }
```

Anyone spot anything? Thanks!

Comment: I think I figured it out. Needed to add wildcard to the posts paths:
`match /{path=**}/posts/{postId} {
 allow read;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Needed to add wildcard to the posts paths:

`match /{path=**}/posts/{postId} {  allow read; }`